# Generating "user" and "developer" documentation from the same codebase using Doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm new to Doxygen and I'm trying to document an API I am planning to open source. I'd really like to build two sets of documentation, one for end users of the API and one for those who intend to modify it. Is there a way to tag Doxygen comment blocks in a way such that I can generate "user" and "dev" documentation trees? Is there a better solution to my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your code is structured, you might be able to get away with using two Doxygen config files each including separate source files.  The "user" config file would only list the source files containing the public interface to the API, while the "dev" config file would list all source files for the whole project.

This does mean that all your interfaces (e.g. abstract base classes) will need to be documented with the user in mind, but that is usually not a problem as by definition there is unlikely to be any implementation details in an abstract base class.

All your "dev" documentation then sits in the actual classes implementing the interfaces, which are never seen by the API and can be safely omitted by the "user" Doxygen config file.

Of course if your code isn't structured this way it's not going to work, so the only solution I can think of is to fill your comments with a bunch of [conditional statements](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdif).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Malvineous already said, there is the `\internal` doxygen command.

`\internal` lets you hide or show part of the documentation by changing `INTERNAL_DOCS` in the Doxyfile

More information here: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinternal